# Laravel 5: show value with far away relationship

Tags: relationship, laravel-5.1

I have a doubt and sure you can help me.

If I have a table user with 'work_id' row, and this value is a releated foreing key with the 'id' into 'work' table.

And into 'work' table I have a 'work_competence_id', and is a foreing key to 'work_competence' table.

And into 'work_competece' I have other row, 'competence_id', that is other foreing key, releated with the 'id' value into 'competence' table...

How can I get competence 'name' (for example) into my view.

I made some easy things, like show the work's name of each user, using

```
public function work()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Work', 'id', 'work_id');
}
```

I put this code into User model.
And I use it into view with:

```
{{ $user->work->name }}
```

But, how is possible to do with so many relationships like I comment above??

Thank you!!

Comment: Did you look at [hasManyThrough](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, try:

```
public function competence(){
    return this->work()->competence();
}
```

and in Work model create competence method

Answer (score 0):

You can jump between more than just one relation:

```
// Work class
public function competence(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Competence', 'id', 'competence_id');
}
```

Then:

```
public function work(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Work', 'id', 'work_id');
}
```

Finally in your view:

```
{{ $user->work->competence->name }}
```